# Find a JsValue in JsObject In Scala

Tags: json, scala

How can I make a recursive function which finds a JsValue in JsObject, for example:
Function input: JsObject and path as String
Examples:

Input for JsObject:

```
{
"name": "Zvi"
parents: {
 "father": {
  "name": "myFatherName",
  "dob": "10/10/70"
  }
}
}
```

and for path Example:

1. path = notExistsField
   the output will be None
2. path = name
   the input will be Some("Zvi")
3. path = parents
   the output will be

```
   Some({
 "father": {
  "name": "myFatherName",
  "dob": "10/10/70"
  }
})
```

4. parents.father
   the output will be:

```
Some({
  "name": "myFatherName",
  "dob": "10/10/70"
  })
```

5. parents.father.name
   the output will be "myFatherName"

Tests Example:

```
"deepSearch" - {
      val payload: JsObject = Json.parse(
        """{
          |  "key1": 1,
          |  "key2": {
          |    "key1": "value21",
          |    "key2": {
          |      "key1": 221
          |    }
          |  },
          |}""".stripMargin).as[JsObject]
      "found" - {
        "nested" in {
          // In Nested Object
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key2.key1").get shouldBe JsString("value21")
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key2.key2.key1").get shouldBe JsNumber(221)
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key2.key2").get shouldBe Json.parse("{\"key1\": 221}")
        }
        "top-level" in {
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key1").get shouldBe JsNumber(1)
        }
      }
      "not found" - {
        "nested" in {
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key2.key2.key1.notExists").isEmpty shouldBe true
          service.deepSearch(payload,"key2.key2.notExists").isEmpty shouldBe true
        }
        "top-level" in {
          service.deepSearch(payload,"Boom").isEmpty shouldBe true
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to JsObject from any specific library or you want to create your own json/JsObject type which support above functions?

Comment: My Own @PritamKadam

Comment: have created your JsObject data type? how does it look?

Comment: @PritamKadam I did the following code (In the comments), do you have some suggesting?

Comment: play-json has exactly similar api, maybe you want to take a look or use that directly

Comment: @PritamKadam can you redirect me, please?

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-json

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson#Traversing-a-JsValue-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following implementation, Is there any suggestions to prettier code

```
def deepSearch(payload: JsValue, path: String): JsLookupResult = {
    path indexOf (".") match {

      // For the Base case:
      case base if base < 0 => (payload \ path)

      // For the Step case:
      case found if found >= 0 =>
        val untilFirstDot = path.substring(0, found)
        (payload \ untilFirstDot) match {
          case JsDefined(newPayload) => deepSearch(newPayload, path.substring(found + 1))
          case undefined: JsUndefined => undefined
        }
    }
  }
```